# mysql insert query does not work from php

Tags: php, mysql

```
$qry ="insert into `$table`(Number) values('".$msg2."')";
$result = mysql_query($qry);
```

If this query is executed from php, a new row is created but no value is getting inserted. Although the id column gets auto incremented. Is there anything wrong with the formatting of msg2?

Comment: are you sure that variable `$msg2` has a value?

Comment: `var_dump($msg2);` and check if it is empty

Comment: `$result = mysql_query($qry) or die(mysql_error());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the datatype of the column - Number in PHPMYADMIN

Answer (score 0):

Print the value of $qry and see if it's appropriate. IE if you paste it into mysql console would it do what you expect?

Also - use a prepared statement next time. This approach is prone to injection style attacks.

Comment: Fyi It works in localhost using WAMP. So, what might be the issue? I'm using this is a free hosting site.

Answer (score 0):

Pls check this one

```
$qry ="INSERT INTO $table(`Number`) VALUES ('$msg2')";
if($result = mysql_query($qry)){}
else{
 echo mysql_error();
}
```

Comment: This is good advice. But it belongs in a comment instead of an answer, since it's not likely to solve the poster's problem on its own.

Answer (score -1):

Try with

```
$qry ="insert into `$table`(Number) values('$msg2')";
$result = mysql_query($qry);
```

Comment: and this changes things how? while the OP's string concatentation is indicative of cargo cult programming, it is not wrong. your version doesn't change anything.